# Using non-cls compliant types in abstract methods

Tags: c#, code-analysis, abstract, cls-compliant

I have an external assembly that I use, and for whatever reason it does not specify CLS Compliance. So, this causes a lot of my code to be marked as non-cls compliant. The problem I'm running into is the following:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    //Compiler Error CS3011
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public abstract object SomeMethod(ExternalNonCompliantType arg);
}

public abstract class SomeClass
{
    //Argument type 'External.ExternalNonCompliantType' is not CLS-compliant
    public abstract object SomeMethod(ExternalNonCompliantType arg);
}
```

---

CS3011:

> A class member cannot be both abstract and non-compliant with
>   the Common Language Specification (CLS). The CLS specifies that all
>   class members shall be implemented.

I'm really not sure what to do here...

Answer (score 2):

- What is the expected use of the code that you are writing?
- Can you just make your whole assembly as `[CLSComplaint(false)]`?

If your assembly is also not-compliant, then you should be ok with this kind of code.  You can also try to mark the one class as Non-Compliant.  I've always just marked the whole assembly.

If this is just your code, and you aren't distributing it as a library, it shouldn't be an issue and you don't need to worry too much about CLS compliance.

The one exception is if you are writing something internally that you expect to be able to re-use in a wide variety of other CLR languages like F#, vb.net, ironpython, boo, M, scala, etc.  Thats probably not the case; most apps are just that - apps.

Comment: I'm writing a library I plan to distribute, and I want my library to be CLS Compliant. I will give an upvote because the suggestion of marking the entire class as non-cls compliant made the warning go away, which makes sense. I was just hoping there was a better way.

Comment: If you are writing a library, then yeah I suppose it matters :) Most of us don't.  In reality, if the expected consumers are the same language (c#) then there will be no problems using it, but it's not pretty for anyone down the line having to mark as non-cls compliant.